# performance enhancements when checking items of a datatable

Tags: vb.net, .net-4.0

```
            Public myGameList As DataTable = Nothing

            Dim tmpGameList As DataTable = fullGameList.Copy

            For Each dr As DataRow In tmpGameList.Rows
                    gameID = dr("gameID")
                    If CanViewOnGameList(gameID) Then
                        If CanEditGameContent(gameID) _
                        OrElse CanEditGameInfo(gameID) Then
                            dr("isEditableGame") = 1
                            dr.AcceptChanges()
                        End If
                        If CanPlayGame(gameID) Then
                            dr("isPlayableGame") = 1
                            dr.AcceptChanges()
                        End If
                    Else
                        dr.Delete()
                    End If
                Next
                tmpGameList.AcceptChanges()
                myGameList = tmpGameList
```

Hi,

I have a game website written .net 4.6(vb) that lists a number of games that users can potentially play.

When a user logs in, the application uses a for/each loop to check user permissions on each game to see if 
that game should be added to a datatable of games that the user can see/play/edit.

This worked fine when there were only 100 or so games, but now I have over 1500 games and the for/each loop is really
starting to slow things down.

So I was wondering, is there a faster way of checking user permissions on a datatable?

Thanks!

Comment: Is the data stored in a database? The result you are looking would be much faster if the query was done there.

Comment: What do the `Can`**Something**`(gameId)` methods look like?  What data type is `gameID`?  One thing you could do is instead of `dr("gameID")` ( a string lookup to find the column ordinal) is to define an variable (`Dim gameIdIndex As Int32 = tmpGameList.Columns("gameId").Ordinal`)  and use that instead. i.e. `dr(gameIdIndex)`.